# Rails early return if before_action attribute set fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to perform a db lookup using the incoming request's `remote_ip` before any controller method is hit in order to set a particular controller class attribute. However if the lookup fails (if no object is linked to the request IP) I would like to immediately return a `404` response.

For example:

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_instance_or_404

   def index
     # do something with @instance
   end

   private
     def set_instance_or_404
       @instance = Model.find_by(ip_address: request.remote_ip)
       # or if no instance is found, immediately return a 404 without hitting "index" method (or any other method for that matter)
     end
end
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception, which will stop the action and return a 404. Or you can `render` or `redirect` which will also stop the action.  See [Rails Filters](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters) docs.  Here are examples of each.

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_instance_or_404

  def index
    # do something with @instance
  end

  private
    def set_instance_or_404
      @instance = Model.find_by(ip_address: request.remote_ip)
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @instance # returns 404
    end
end

class Controller < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_instance_or_404

  def index
    # do something with @instance
  end

  private
    def set_instance_or_404
      @instance = Model.find_by(ip_address: request.remote_ip)
      render(status: 404, inline: "Instance not found") unless @instance 
    end
end
```

Comment: Bill Doughty you are a legend! Thank you so much

Comment: Just a heads up that I had to change your `unless` logic to have the condition placed last, rather than in the beginning. For example: `raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound unless @instance`

Comment: Ah, good catch, I'll update the answer.  I was spooling from memory, and forgot single line Ruby conditionals in the moment.  Thanks!